# Optimising multidimensional array performance- MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, multidimensional-array

Communication overhead (parfor) and preallocating for speed (for) in Multidimensional Arrays

I am getting two warnings in the following script at the places indicated by **'s

1. Variable is indexed but not sliced... (the array A shown by ** in the second parfor loop) - What is causing this and how can it be avoided?
2. The variable appears to change size on every loop... (the array Sol shown by ** in the for loop) - Maybe I am not doing it right, but preallocating memory hasn't worked.

*Edit: My initial idea was to preallocate the arrays (as done in the first parfor loop) so that it will execute the rest of the script faster (the full version of the script repeats various array operations similar to the second parfor and for loops).*

Any suggestions? :)

```
N = 1000;

parfor i=1:N
    A(:,:,i) = rand(2);
    X(:,:,i) = rand(2,1);
    Sol1(1,1,i) = zeros();
    Sol2(1,1,i) = zeros();
    Sol(2,1,i) = zeros();
end


t0 = tic;

parfor i=1:N
    Sol1(1,:,i) = A(1,:,i)*X(:,1,i);
    Sol2(1,:,i) = **A**(2,:,i)*X(:,1,i);
end

for i=1:N
    **Sol**(:,1,i) = [Sol1(1,:,i);Sol2(1,:,i)];
end

toc(t0);
```

Comment: How did you preallocate the memory?

Comment: @bdecaf I just realised that what I did in the first parfor loop (my idea of preallocating) is completely wrong! Whats the best way to preallocate for multidimension arrays?

Comment: Basically I do `NaN(3,4,5,...)`, just write the size of dimensions in there in order (you could do the same with `zeros` or `ones`- but I prefer to see when a value has not been allocated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pre-allocation is not right - you need to do each in a single call.

```
A = rand(2, 2, N);
X = rand(2, 1, N);
Sol1 = zeros(1, 1, N);
Sol2 = zeros(1, 1, N);
Sol = zeros(2, 1, N); % not really needed actually.
```

In your PARFOR loop, you can avoid 'broadcasting' `A` by using a syntax that MATLAB understands as slicing

```
parfor i = 1:N
    tmp = A(:, :, i);
    Sol1(1, :, i) = tmp(1,:) * X(:, 1, i);
    Sol2(1, :, i) = tmp(2,:) * X(:, 1, i);
end
```

Finally, I think you can do this as a vectorised concatenation like so:

```
Sol = [Sol1; Sol2];
```

**EDIT**
On the GPU, you can use [`pagefun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pagefun.html) to get the whole job done in a single call, like so:

```
Ag = gpuArray.rand(2,2,N);
Xg = gpuArray.rand(2,1,N);
Sol = pagefun(@mtimes, Ag, Xg);
```

Comment: Thank you, almost a 45% speed up!

I have noticed that its faster to do the entire matrix multiplication in one go, rather than break it into row 1 x column and row 2 x column, and concatenate as I have done above.

Therefore, any suggestions for optimising the following section of the script?
`t2 = tic;

parfor i=1:N
    Sol(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i)*X(:,:,i);
end

toc(t2);`

Comment: Also, worth mentioning that my final aim is to run this parallel code on a GPU

Comment: Thanks, `pagefun` was really helpful and I got a massive speedup! Is it possible to use other GPU-ready functions instead of `@mtimes`? Eg. I want to calculate the `norm` for `Ag(1,:,N)`, can it be done using `pagefun`?

Comment: Could I ask: which version of `norm` are you most interested in?